Pipeline Failed When Running Azure CLI Task
Good morning:
In Azure DevOps I'm setting up a pipeline that, based on a repository with a docker project (with a Docker-Compose file), automates the completion and publication of the service. The thing is that for the following task it gives me a route error:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Docker Build
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          docker build -t service:$(tag).
          docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar


/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1713529050063.sh
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore

#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2163565617/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist


I don't think he's looking for it in the right folder, but I don't know where to look for it or how. Any ideas?

This first part of the Pipeline looks like this (error en la tarea AzureCLI@2):


trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' 

variables:
  tag: 1.0.0-$(Build.BuildId)
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  acrINT: 'XXXXX'
  aKSINT: 'XXXXX'
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'XXXXXX'
  azureContainerRegistry: 'XXXXX'
  dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
  resourceGroupName: ''
  clusterName: ''


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build 
  jobs:
  - job: Build_code
    displayName: Build 
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
      inputs:
        version: 8.x
        performMultiLevelLookup: true
        includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
        azureContainerRegistry: '$(azureContainerRegistry)'
        dockerComposeFile: '$(dockerComposeFile)'
        additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'
        dockerComposeFileArgs: 'DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE='
        action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
        dockerComposeCommand: 'build --parallel'

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Docker Build
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          docker build -t service:$(tag) .
          docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar


    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
        artifact: 'service-artifact'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'`

Ejecutar el Pipeline y que se cree el servicio


The error indicates the Dockerfile is not found under the default working directory. Please follow below items for a check:

Docker is case-sensitive. Ensure that the Dockerfile is named exactly as Dockerfile (without any extension) and not dockerFile.

Check which repo and branch is the pipeline build is running on, confirm the Dockerfile exists on the correct repo and branch.


If the issue persists, it's recommended to find Dockerfile(find . -name "Dockerfile" ) before build:

If Dockerfile is not under root directory, you can add workingDirectory for the task:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Docker Build
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      find . -name "Dockerfile"             # try to find the Dockerfile before build.
      docker build -t service:$(tag) .
      docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar
    workingDirectory: Docker                # the Dockerfile folder


Thanks for responding. Maybe the problem comes from the assembly of the Pipeline. The purpose of this is , from the Azure repository where there is a NetCore project with Docker-Compose, build, create the docker image and upload the service to the azure container. I'm not sure I'm using the good tasks. What would be the three tasks to use?

The DockerCompose@0 task contains different actions, it supports build service and push services.  After build, add a new DockerCompose@0 to push to ACR.  However it's a new topic which is not related to current issue on the ticket. May i know if above Dockerfile not found resolved? It's recommended to raise a new ticket for the new query and share the link here, glad to help.

I'm still working on it. Since I'm trying what you told me, I'll open a new thread if I can't solve it and if I can solve it I'll reply to this one. Thanks in advance.

You are welcome! Feel free to let me know if you have any queries, glad to help!

Now it finds the Dockerfile but fails to execute the commands. These commands work locally and if you run Docker-Compose (DockerCompose@0) But if I run docker build -t service:$(tag) . in the AzureCLI@2 task it gives me the following error.

Dockerfile:11
9 |     ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
10 |     WORKDIR /src
11 | >>> COPY ["GNF_Inventario/GNF_Inventario.csproj", "GNF_Inventario/"]
12 |     RUN dotnet restore "./GNF_Inventario/./GNF_Inventario.csproj"
13 |     COPY . .
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 584d62f5-11d9-4074-87e4-acacf60905a6::809ah34b92o8ga026wkrxiy3c: "/GNF_Inventario/GNF_Inventario.csproj": not found
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist
